# Opening files with sequential filenames

Tags: c, file

For an assignment I'm trying to output multiple files with different names e.g. `file_1.dat`, `file_2.dat` etc. I was hoping I could do this the same way as `fprintf` and `fscanf` but that doesn't work.

What would anyone suggest (code below is what I used)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("testing_%d.dat", i,"w");
    }   
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried debugging by setting a break point or printing information to STDOUT?

Comment: You will need to construct a string that contains the filename, and then pass *that* to `fopen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first write the file name to a `char []` by using `sprintf()`, and then pass it to `fopen()`.

```
char myFile[200];
sprintf(myFile, "testing_%d.dat", i);
file = fopen(myFile, "w");
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` should come in handy.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        char buf[100]
        FILE *file;
        sprintf(buf, "testing_%d.dat", i);
        file = fopen(buf, "w");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` should be an array of `FILE *`.  Also, `fopen` doesn't format a string like `printf`.  Change your file opening logic to something like this:

```
#define NUM_FILES        (3)
#define FILE_NAME_LENGTH (100)

FILE *pFileArr[NUM_FILES];
char filename[FILE_NAME_LENGTH];

for(i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++)
{
    snprintf(filename, FILE_NAME_LENGTH, "testing_%d.dat", i);
    pFileArr[i] = fopen(filename, "w");
}
```